# Local database solutions for windows phone development

Tags: database, windows, sqlite, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql

I am maintaining a simple set of records. I want to store these records as table on my Windows phone.

I have come across Linq-to-SQL. My question is, is it the default database provided by the Windows phone system just as SQLite is provided by ANDROID?

Is Linq-to-SQL used by the Windows phone native apps like Contacts Manager?

I have also come across SQLite support for Windows phone. I am able to install the necessary extensions and packages required.

My question here is, when I will deploy my application on the phone, is there a need to install the SQLite library separately first for that phone?

When we include the extension in our Visual Studio IDE then while deploying my application on the phone does the IDE take care of installation of SQLite on the phone?

Comment: Linq-to-SQL is an **ORM** (object-relation mapper) targeted at the full versions of **SQL Server** - not exactly something you want to install on your Windows phone!

Comment: Yeah i got it. LINQ TO SQL will help me in writing and querying the data stored on file in local file. But is there any native database provided by Microsoft for windows phone ?

Comment: Nop you have install the `SQLite` for your solution, by right clicking your solution > Manage Nuget Packages > select the extension and install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite's distribution contains everything needed to make use of a local database file asset packaged within its DLL that you reference in your project when you pull in its NuGet package. No additional installations or assets are required by users of your applications.

If you are interested in Microsoft technologies for use with your project, you're looking for SQL Compact 3.5. Compact 4.0 is not currently supported by Windows Phone. You can create a new compact database SDF file and add it to your project as an embedded resource, then access it with a connection string as simple as `isostore:/FileName.sdf`. You'll still need to generate a DB context and entities to make use of the database, but I've found that I can use LINQ-to-SQL's ORM and import the generated classes, removing the two unsupported interface context constructors that aren't in the Windows Phone library.

Comment: Thank you. That was the one i was looking for

Comment: @hcnimkar If this answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it or marking it as the answer.

Comment: Is the default database used by linq to sql is isolated storages?

Comment: For a local database instance, yes, you can specify any path in local storage to either have the context create the database with your schema using [CreateDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase(v=vs.110).aspx) or utilize a prepackaged SDF you've generated and embedded as a resource in the application.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent Windows phone project I used [Lex.db](https://github.com/demigor/lex.db) and was very happy with the ease of use, performance and platform flexibility